# How do I delete an entity by passing "id" as parameter?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

"Type 'DeleteResult' is missing the following properties from type 'TodoEntity': id, version, title, description, and 2 more." - This is my error.

```
async delete(
        id   : string,
    ) : Promise<TodoEntity> {
        const desiredTodo = await this.getOne(id);
        const deletedTodo = await this.toDoRepository.delete(desiredTodo);
        return deletedTodo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `DeleteResult` doesn't match the return type you've told typescript you're going to send back (`TodoEntity`). If you mean to return the `TodoEntity` you can return the `desiredTodo` you get from the `this.getOne()` call. Otherwise, you need to update the return type of the method.